# F String not printing

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to print results into the terminal, but the `f-string` does not seem to be working, as shown here:

```
print(
    f'Financial Analysis\n'
    '----------------------\n'  
    'Total Months {monthnum}\n' 
    'Total: ${pl}\n'
    'Greatest increase in profits: {greatim} ({greati}) \n'
    'Greatest decrease in profits: {greatdm} ({greatd})'
    )
```

The rest of the code is avaliable on [this repository](https://github.com/crisbusa92/PythonIntroHW)

Comment: Complete running programs are preferred on stackoverflow. Can you add the variables in your f string so we can run it and post fixes more easily?

Answer (score 6):

In your code only the first string is an `f` string. You need to make them all f strings if you want interpolation.

Alternatively, you can use f strings with multiline quotes (i.e. `''' '''`). That might be a better solution here:

```
monthnum = 10
pl = "some pl"
greatim = "gim"
greati = 'gti'
greatdm = 'gdm'
greatd = 'gd'

print(f'''Financial Analysis
----------------------
Total Months {monthnum} 
Total: ${pl}
Greatest increase in profits: {greatim} ({greati})
Greatest decrease in profits: {greatdm} ({greatd})'''
)
```

Prints:

```
Financial Analysis
----------------------
Total Months 10 
Total: $some pl
Greatest increase in profits: gim (gti)
Greatest decrease in profits: gdm (gd)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that Python is willing to combine f-strings and non f-strings together without generating an error.

Comment: Hi @MarkRansom, agreed—it's not obvious that it should work. I think this is addressed in [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#concatenating-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use the `f''` in the line that you have referenced the variable, like this:

```
print(
    'Financial Analysis\n'
    '----------------------\n'  
    f'Total Months {monthnum}\n' 
    f'Total: ${pl}\n'
    f'Greatest increase in profits: {greatim} ({greati}) \n'
    f'Greatest decrease in profits: {greatdm} ({greatd})'
    )
```

In your case I also think using the `.format()` method at the end of the string could be cleaner, but that's a personal choice.